# Rstudio editor seems slow for highlighted code on large screen

Tags: performance, editor, ubuntu-14.04, rstudio, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Rstudio v0.99.891 under Ubuntu 14.04LTS on a 2014 Laptop with 8GB RAM. I recently started to use RStudio again to edit RMarkdown-Files on an external monitor with an resolution of 2560x1440 pixels.

It seems, that the editor ([ACE](https://ace.c9.io/#higlighter=&nav=about)) seems to have problems, when the display is quite large and the code needs to be highlighted. I like the source pane to fill half of my screen and this is when I notice the biggest **lag in navigating the code**.

When I decrease the editor size the delay gets diminished and when I turn off the syntax highlighting, the lag vanishes completely. (Similar to this documented user experience: [Poor performance of editor (esp. markdown)](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200662147-Poor-performance-of-editor-esp-markdown-)

*What can I do to have a better performance?*

Comment: There were some recent performance improvements added as part of a patch release of RStudio (currently available as RStudio v0.99.893) -- could you give that a shot and see if the performance improves at all? You could also try the latest daily build at http://dailies.rstudio.com/.

Comment: I did use v0.99.891 and did switch to the daily build 0.99.1150 just now. I'm just with my laptop now, so I can't test this fully, but the editor seems quite a bit faster already. Nice!